# Was Stranger in a Strange Land the first sci fi novel to deal with the mind body concept of visualized intention and its effect on the physical body?

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, stranger-in-a-strange-land

The protagonist in Stranger in a Strange Land JMS comes from Mars, taught by spirits that sail across the landscape (sages? Monks? Gurus?).  Shortly after arriving he starts to grok what's going on and chameleon like change his body and behavior to maximize his interaction with the earth. Mind body visualization intention yoga. Is this the first time this concept appears in sci fi?

Comment: Thanks 14111 I"ll give it a shot.Yoga as well as some other disciplines is not just the physical practice involving poses designed to improve balance,strength, flexibility and proprioception that most of us are familiar with. There are yamas and nyamas(roughly rules of behavior) such as kindness, compassion, respect,not stealing others time,etc. there is the increased ability of the practitioner to read or be conscious of his/her body and its health, strength, condition in the present moment. Value is placed on being in the moment (present) in order to experience living more fully

Comment: As apposition to living in the future (where we can never be) or the past where we can never be again. In order to achieve a desired outcome, one must create a detailed accurate image or visualization of what one wants. Without a vision one wanders aimlessly. Focus and intention affect the body directly. Focus on form and performance result in improvement. It in now recognized that the single most important factor in recovery from trauma and disease is attitude weather positive or negative.

Comment: It's been decades since I read "Stranger" but I am sure I didn't imagine the Or misrember the references in the text to JMS intentionally changing his physicality, and to some extent determining outcomes almost effortlessly.

Comment: So long before my introduction to yoga and eastern thought I took as an adolescent this implied philosophy and began to use it in my life.

Comment: While I can't think of any earlier examples off the top of my head, I highly doubt Heinlein was the first to write a character who changes things by visualizing the desired change in detail (which I think is the main point of your question), as the pattern of thoughts that the mental model of a thing is intimately connected to or is in some way the same as the real thing has existed for a very long time (it is what's usually called [magical thinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magical_thinking)).

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your comments. Obviously this pup needs to do a bit more study to catch up with the big dogs. I might have to as I said else where revisit my old sci fi readings.

Comment: Close and not close. Not, because of the object lodged in his brain being the vehicle and that is not really the idea in the yogic sense. In yoga it is not about making physical items appear. It is about creating an outcome that is desired by thinking the desire through as completely and accurately as possible. Not just saying I want to met someone. But I want to meet someone with these qualities experiences abilities desires philosophies etc etc so the target is so well described in the mind of the searcher that his/her perceptions and resolution are highly tuned and the right target glows.